# purpose of Batch_size in image augmentation in tensorflow keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am trying to do image augmentation using keras and tensorflow. However, i couldn't understand the impact of batch_size parameter on the augmented data. I gave 1 image as input, code ran for 3 times, my output were only 3 images (code attached below). I have tried to change batch_size and iterations multiple times, even chatgpt says, i should have 6 images (3 iterations, 2 batch_size) as output in this case.

Anyhow, my idea was output image (for one image input) =  batch_size  * 1 (for each iteration)
so if batch_size isn't a multiplier per image input, then what is its purpose? or what am i missing?

further info regarding code:
https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, array_to_img, img_to_array, load_img

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rotation_range=40,
        width_shift_range=0.2,
        height_shift_range=0.2,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True,
        fill_mode='nearest')

img = load_img('/content/library.png')  
x = img_to_array(img)  
x = x.reshape((1,) + x.shape)  

i = 0
for batch in datagen.flow(x, batch_size=2,
                          save_to_dir='libra', save_prefix='lib', save_format='jpeg'):
    i += 1
    if i > 2:
        break
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with TF/keras, but could it be, it is overwritting the previously created images on the disk? try displaying the images and make sure you get what you expect, and when you do, then I guess that would narrow it down to being overwritten!

Comment: Thank you Hossein for your kind response. I did check, its not overwriting - path of generated images are different from single input image.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator), `ImageDataGenerator` provides a generator that generates batches of data. `flow` would take an array of images, and each time you iterate over the generator (with a `for` loop, list comprehension, or similar), it would output a batch of images. You can control the size of the batch with the `batch_size` parameter.
So if you have an array x with 100 images in it, `.flow(x, batch_size=32)` would give you 32 different augmented images in `batch` on each loop iteration. If you have fewer images than the batch size, they will not be output multiple times to fill up `batch_size`.

Additionally, if you use a Generator, tf.Dataset or similar, you don't specify a `batch_size` in `model.fit()`, as the data already comes in batches. ([Link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit), info box for `batch_size`)

One info though, in the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator) it is stated that `ImageDataGenerator` is deprecated:

> Deprecated: tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator is not
> recommended for new code. Prefer loading images with
> tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory and transforming the
> output tf.data.Dataset with preprocessing layers. For more
> information, see the tutorials for loading images and augmenting
> images, as well as the preprocessing layer guide.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind response mhenning. I know what documentation says, run the code above, it would not work - in terms of batch multiplier per loop. Even if you give batch_size = 32, generated images would be based on how many times loop ran. (like 5/6 even if batch_size is 32.

when i had a very structured binary data of 1000 images each, it worked. For a singular image manipulation batch_size parameter is failing (code above). 

Regarding ImageDataGenerator, i used it for image manipulation parameters, not for sole purpose of uploading images from directory to collab.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a follow up question. As I mentioned, the use of the `batch_size` parameter is not to get multiple images out of one. It is just used to split stuff up in batches, and if there is not enouth stuff to split, it is not split nor muliplied.